# how to put a raw char * to AVPacket

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I have a compressed image stored in a char * and I want to put it back to an AVPacket so that I can put it into a ffmpeg decoder. Can someone show how to do this? Any sample or tutorial would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I show you a sample code related with some ffmpeg encoder.

```
static int encode_frame(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVPacket *pkt,
                        const AVFrame *pict, int *got_packet) {
    unsigned char *buf;
    int ret, bufLen;
    int64_t maxsize;

    // Store image data to buf variable.
    buf = ....
    // Calculate buf length.
    bufLen = ....

    // Allocate AVPacket.
    maxsize = FF_MIN_BUFFER_SIZE + avctx->width * avctx->height * 9;
    if ((ret = ff_alloc_packet2(avctx, pkt, maxsize)) < 0)
        return ret;

    // Copy buf to AVPacket.
    memcpy(pkt->data, buf, bufLen);
    pkt->size = bufLen;

    *got_packet = 1;

    return 0;
}
```